# Simple string operation within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to do some simple string operation within ng-repeat and display the result outside of the ng-repeat element, like this:

```
<span ng-repeat="f in fields" ng-init="result = '';">
    <span ng-init="result = result + f.name;"></span>
</span>

{{result}}
```

How do I keep the 'result' variable in the same scope throughout the operation?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish / what is the use case? Seems like there would be a better way to do what you're looking to accomplish. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I've managed to figure it out. I simply wrap the whole thing in another span like this: <span ng-init="vars = {}; vars.result = '';"> and then use vars.result throughout the code.

Comment: Yea that's what I was going to suggest, but honestly you can accomplish this another way (depending on the use case) - most likely this isn't the best way to go about it.

Comment: @Nick Hi Nick, since the ng-repeat is redundant, and does not show anything useful in the HTML you can just move this code into the controller, I am not knowing your exact use case so check this simple example on how to do the thing done in `ng-repeat` inside the controller here [`JSFiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/771x47nz/)

Answer (score -1):

Managed to figure it out. I simply wrap the whole thing in another span like this:

```
<span ng-init="vars = {}; vars.result = '';">
    <span ng-repeat="f in fields">
        <span ng-init="vars.result = vars.result + f.name;"></span>
    </span>

    {{vars.result}}
</span>
```

Comment: Seems like "result" should be a $scope variable to be processed inside a Controller. But it is an interesting exercise anyway